# f# member constraints and IEnumerable collections

Tags: generics, f#, ienumerable, inline, type-inference

I'm new to F# and today I saw the member constraint feature of F#.

I was thinking of if one could (ab)use it in the following way...

Say I want to iterate get the texts of the items in a ListView. I could do it like this:

```
let listView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView()
let itemTexts = 
    listView.Items
    |> Seq.cast<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem>
    |> Seq.map (fun item -> item.Text)
```

The Seq.cast above is not type safe and kind of ugly.

What I was thinking was this:

```
> let item (i:int) = listView.Items.Item i;;

val item : int -> System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
```

So the type of the `IEnumerable` is in fact encoded into the class, just in a round-about way.

The example of member constraints I saw was the following:

```
type Cat() = 
    member this.Walk() = printfn "cat walk"
type Dog() = 
    member this.Walk() = printfn "dog walk"

let adapter() = 
    let cat = Cat()
    let dog = Dog()
    let inline walk (x : ^T) = (^T : (member Walk : unit->unit) (x))
    walk(cat)
    walk(dog)
```

I got the idea that it's a bit similar to what I'd want to do above.

Could this be used to create a function to be use like the following instead?

```
let itemTexts = 
    listView.Items
    |> Seq.asSeq
    |> Seq.map (fun item -> item.Text)
```

**Edit**: The idea was to implement a general `Seq.asSeq` extension method that'd take something that implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` and that has a strongly typed `Item`-member as above and then invoke `Seq.cast` with the corresponding type from the `Item`-member.

Here's my first fumbling attempts:

```
let listView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView()
let items = 
    listView.Items

type cat() = 
    member this.Item (i:int) = "cat walk"
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
       member this.GetEnumerator() = ((seq { yield (this.Item 0) }) :> System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()

type dog() = 
    member this.Item (i:int) = 6
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
       member this.GetEnumerator() = ((seq { yield (this.Item 0) }) :> System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()

let cat = cat()
let dog = dog()

let inline asSeq (x : ^t) =
    let dummy _ = (^t : (member Item : int -> 'a) (x, 0))
    Seq.cast<'a> x
```

This almost works, but not for the real type!

```
> cat;;
val it : cat = seq ["cat walk"]
> asSeq cat;;
val it : seq<string> = seq ["cat walk"]
> asSeq dog;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [6]
> asSeq items;;

  asSeq items;;
  ------^^^^^

C:\...\stdin(5,7): error FS0001: The type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not support any operators named 'Item'
>
```

I guess it's my fake-types that do not properly reflect the .NET indexed properties...

Any help?

**Edit 2:** This actually works!

```
let inline asSeq (x : ^t) =
    let dummy _ = (^t : (member Item : int -> 'a with get) (x, 0))
    Seq.cast<'a> x
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you went from not wanting `Seq.cast` to statically discovered type parameters - I think I'm missing what you're ultimately trying to do here. You could extend the `ListView` type to include `ToEnumerable()` method that would return a strongly typed sequence: `seq { for item in this.Items -> item }`; that would get rid of the cast.

Comment: It strikes me as minor hole that the Collection types can be comprehended into a `seq { }` expression because `for` can figure the type, but can't be used directly as a sequence.

Comment: Oh, cool! I didn't know `seq { for item in listView.Items -> item }` would actually infer the type correctly. I wonder if there's any magic behind that?

Comment: @johv - F#'s `for` support for non-`IEnumerable<_>` values actually has two different flavors, as the spec explains in section [6.5.6](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818858).  Basically, the compiler looks for a `GetEnumerator()` method whose return type supports `MoveNext : unit -> bool` and `Current : 't` members.  If `'t` is something other than `obj`, then it uses that; otherwise it sees if there's also an `Item` indexed property with a more specific type and inserts a dynamic cast to that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something along [these lines](http://fssnip.net/4f), in which case your code is nearly right.

Note that one issue is that you're attempting to use indexed properties interchangeably with methods, but you're not doing it quite right: for an indexed property named `Item`, the method's actual name will be `get_Item` (alternatively, you can use the syntax `member Item : int -> 'a with get` instead of using the `get_Item` method directly).

Comment: Yes that worked! I did want to use cast, just using Item to pick up or bind the type.